# Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource : Schema-validation: missing table [association_value_entry]

Tags: spring-boot, event-sourcing, axon

When I compile my spring-boot project with Axon while attempting to implement event sourcing, this is the error I am receiving:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing table [association_value_entry]

I am using MySQL Database and Intellij

The error is outlined below:

> Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
>   2020-03-14 15:43:53.035 ERROR 1719 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing table [association_value_entry]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1796) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1108) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at com.seng401.mango.MangoApplication.main(MangoApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
>       at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
>       at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
>   Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing table [association_value_entry]
>       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:403) ~[spring-orm-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:378) ~[spring-orm-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1855) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1792) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
>       ... 21 common frames omitted
>   Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing table [association_value_entry]
>       at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaValidator.validateTable(AbstractSchemaValidator.java:121) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaValidatorImpl.validateTables(GroupedSchemaValidatorImpl.java:42) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaValidator.performValidation(AbstractSchemaValidator.java:89) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaValidator.doValidation(AbstractSchemaValidator.java:68) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:192) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:73) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.(SessionFactoryImpl.java:314) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:468) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1237) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
>       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391) ~[spring-orm-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
>       ... 25 common frames omitted

Upon looking at other sources I have concluded its not a missing dependency error. (or so I think, as I have tried adding Hibernate dependencies and ended up getting another error altogether.) I am most concerned with the "Schema-validation: missing table [association_value_entry]" at the end of the first error.

What does this mean? 
How can I fix this?

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having a look at your project/sample would help but I am assuming you are using any kind of database migration tool (like Flyway).
In this case, you have to provide one 'first migration' script yourself containing all the Axon tables.

Looking at Axon repository, I can see this [issue](https://github.com/AxonFramework/AxonFramework/issues/1343) which pretty much is the same problem as yours and give you a specific answer regarding tables that are needed:

> Axon requires a set of entities to be created to be able to work, which are the association_value_entry, saga_entry and token_entry tables.

Comment: I am using JDBC Connector, is that what you're referring to? Do I need to manually add the tables to MySQL Workbench? Are these tables the only ones required: "association_value_entry, saga_entry and token_entry"?

Comment: In general, yes.
But as it is stated at the issue I pointed before, you can have it working in 2 different ways.

Having a look at a sample or at least your configuration would be extremely helpful!

Comment: So I updated the database to update so all missing schemas are now added. But now I am getting a different error with entityManagerFactory : "org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]"

Comment: As I said before, looking at a sample or at least your configuration would be extremely helpful. Also, for the error reported before, having the complete StackTrace is also needed.